# Django -models Email notification to the User after a change

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

After registration, Need to send a mail to the user after their account was created in the database. Code is running in the server and the database was connected but the email was not received to the **Users**.

Need help in fixing this issue

```
class User(models.Model):
    
    CHOICES= (
    ('manager','Manager'),
      ('hr', 'HR'),
     ('hr manager','HR Manager'),
     ('trainee','Trainee')
)

    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=210)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=210)
    dob=models.DateField(max_length=8) 
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None) 
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None)
    joiningDate=models.DateTimeField(max_length=8)
    userrole=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CHOICES,null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.firstname 

@receiver(pre_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='active')
def active(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_active and User.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk, is_active=False).exists():
        subject = 'Active account'
        mesagge = '%s your account is now active' %(instance.username)
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        send_mail(subject, mesagge, from_email, [instance.email], fail_silently=False)
```

**ERROR**

```
AttributeError at /api/User/
'User' object has no attribute 'is_active'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/User/
Django Version: 2.2.12
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'User' object has no attribute 'is_active'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Based on your question it's unclear to me what is the issue. I need more context. Did you try to debug it? Does the signal receiver get called? Does the condition evaluate to true? Does `send_mail()` work in other cases?

Comment: Another hint is that your topic says "after a change" but then you use the `pre_save`  signal instead of `post_save`.

Comment: Hii, I'm creating API in the rest framework for my project. The client needs to receive an email when the user was created. I'm not that familiar with Django.

Comment: I have tried post_save too but receiving the same...The values are connecting with the DB, no errors all running fine when migration but the mail functionality is not working

Comment: Where does `User. is_active` come from? It doesn't look like it's defined on your model.